# Does the product liability settlement law vary for online purchased products?

Tags: criminal-law, product-liability

In this modern era, most of the products are online purchased. If the product is found defective or harmful, how can we file a product liability settlement claim? Does the process vary from normally purchased products?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn’t differ from shop bought items.